# Add product to wish list in Djagno

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, backend

I want to add a product to the wish-list by clicking on the heart, which then becomes red when the product is in the wish-list. When it is clicked again, it removes it. Here are my functions:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def favorie(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET.get('query', '')
        if query:
            products = Product.objects.filter(Q(nom__icontains=query) |   Q(description__icontains=query))
            return redirect(f'/products?query={query}')

    favories = Favorie.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if favories :
        template = 'favorie.html'
    else:
        template = 'favorie_vide.html'
    return render(request, template , {'favories': favories})

def add_to_favorie(request,id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    favorie, created = Favorie.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, product=product)
    if not created:
        favorie.delete()
    return redirect('detail', id=id)

def remove_from_favorie(request, id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    favorite = Favorie.objects.filter(user=request.user, product=product).first()
    if favorite:
        favorite.delete()
    return redirect('product_detail', id=id)
```

Here is the template where I want to click:

```
<div class="produit p-4 d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column rounded-5 align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <span class="heart-box">
          <img src="{% static 'produit/images/heart-active.jpg' %}" class="heart1 d-none" alt="">
          <img class="heart" src="{% static 'produit/images/heart.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </span>
```

I tried this make this button but nothing changed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to click? I don't see anything with any function/link to click in your html. You could try adding action="/remove_from_post/" and action="/add_to_favorie/" to the img tags.

Comment: i delete it but i add <a href="{% url 'add_to_favorie' id=id %}"> but not work

Comment: Have you defined the url in urls.py?

Comment: yes here : path('favorie', views.favorie, name="favorie"),
    path('datail/<int:id>', views.add_to_favorie, name='add_to_favorie'),

Comment: when i click the heart become red and the page refresh then it become vide and nothing adding in the favorie page

Comment: so add add_to_favorie and remove_from_favorie urls also to your urls.py

Comment: path('add_to_favorie', views.add_to_favorie, name="add_to_favorie"), path('remove_from_favorie'/, views.remove_from_favorie, name="remove_from_favorie". You can then use these as functions...

Comment: nothing change it same nothing adding

Comment: here the new template : <a href="{% url 'add_to_panier' id=id %}">
        <div class="heart-box">
          <img src="{% static 'produit/images/heart-active.jpg' %}" class="heart1 d-none" alt="">
          <img class="heart" src="{% static 'produit/images/heart.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </div>
     </a>

Comment: when i click on the heart the page just refershing and when i remove the url i add in the template the heart become red

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def toggle_favorie(request, id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    if not Favorie.objects.filter(user=request.user, product=product).exits():
        Favorie.objects.create(
            user=request.user, product=product
            )
    else:
        Favorie.objects.get(
            user=request.user, product=product
            ).delete()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={
                'id': id
            }))
# you'll need to change your urls
```

Then add the form in your templates

```
  <form action="{%  url 'your_url_name' #your_product_id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit>
      <span class="heart-box">
          <img src="{% static 'produit/images/heart-active.jpg' %}" class="heart1 d-none" alt="">
          <img class="heart" src="{% static 'produit/images/heart.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </span>
  </button>
  </form>
```

Or you can use js to handle toggle, and using fetch api to make request to your endpoints, you'll just need to change the response to JsonResponse.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse  # Added for AJAX response

# ... your existing imports

@login_required(login_url='login')
def favorie(request):
    # ... your existing code for handling GET requests

def add_to_favorie(request, id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    favorie, created = Favorie.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, product=product)

    if not created:
        favorie.delete()

    return JsonResponse({'in_favories': not created})  # Return AJAX response

# No need for a separate remove_from_favorie view as it's handled in add_to_favorie
```

Template

```
<span class="heart-box">
    <img src="{% static 'produit/images/heart-active.jpg' %}" class="heart1 d-none" alt="Heart filled">
    <img src="{% static 'produit/images/heart.jpg' %}" class="heart" alt="Heart outline">
</span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.heart').click(function() {
            var productId = {{ product.id }};  // Assuming you have product.id in context
            $.ajax({
                url: '/add_to_favorie/' + productId,
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.in_favories) {
                        $('.heart').addClass('d-none');
                        $('.heart1').removeClass('d-none');
                    } else {
                        $('.heart').removeClass('d-none');
                        $('.heart1').addClass('d-none');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```